# cannot call getWriter() after getOutputStream() weblogic error

Tags: java, jsf, weblogic, jsf-1.2, weblogic-10.x

I have a web project Using maven and JSF 1.2 and JDK 1.5

and have Jsp page

```
<title>Celsius to Fahrenheit Convertor</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
  <h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
      <h:outputLabel value="Celsius"></h:outputLabel>
      <h:inputText  value="#{temperatureConvertor.celsius}"></h:inputText>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton action="#{temperatureConvertor.celsiusToFahrenheit}" value="Calculate"></h:commandButton>
    <h:commandButton action="#{temperatureConvertor.reset}" value="Reset"></h:commandButton>
    <h:messages layout="table"></h:messages>
  </h:form>


  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{temperatureConvertor.initial!=true}">
  <h3> Result </h3>
  <h:outputLabel value="Fahrenheit "></h:outputLabel>
  <h:outputLabel value="#{temperatureConvertor.fahrenheit}"></h:outputLabel>
  </h:panelGroup>
</f:view>
</body>
```

When Deploy the application in weblogic 10

the page appear empty and server Log

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: strict servlet API: cannot call getWriter() after getOutputStream()
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.getWriter(ServletResponseImpl.java:299)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:362)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:140)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:155)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:226)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:124)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3395)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2140)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2046)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1366)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)
```

please advice me about this problem and how solve it